# Why forbid cross-domain ajax when script tags work?

Tags: javascript, security, xmlhttprequest

Since it is straightforward to use JSONP in a script tag to fetch data from a different domain, shouldn't we allow XMLHttpRequest to do it as well? It doesn't make much sense to claim it strengthens security when it's possible to work around it, albeit with more messy semantics.

Comment: You need to read about the same origin policy,  i recommend the google browser security handbook.

Answer (score 8):

JSONP only works if the provider allows for it.

If cross domain AJAX worked, one of the first problems would be people posting to other domains in the hope you have an authenticated account there. This is CSRF.

They could GET a page authenticated as you, take your token, and then POST something malicious with your token (which tells the application this is an internal request).

Comment: I am genuinely surprised how many developers are not aware of CSRF.

Comment: Good point. However, it still seems as though improving XMLHttpRequest would be a better solution than script tag hacks. Why not give it its own cookie environment?

Comment: @henle You *could* be authenticated via IP or GET params being passed around.

Comment: @alex: Then people shouldn't authenticate via IP. Problem solved. :)

Comment: @henle You are absolutely right; they shouldn't. But I'm sure some do.

Comment: @henle — they are improving XHR, but it is a hard problem.

Comment: @alex: I'm sure some do too, but that doesn't everyone else should cater for their bad practices.

Comment: @henle — First thing that springs to mind is that it lets a website on the Internet sniff common hostnames and steal data from a company's intranet if someone on the company network visits the site.

Comment: @henle web applications use cookies for authentication,  thats why CSRF is a problem.

Comment: @henle Aw, I'd been capped and being accepted is all I had! :P

Comment: @alex: You've been what, now? :P

Comment: @David Dorward: Right, that's a dealbreaker. You should write an answer or maybe alex wants to add it to his answer!

Comment: @henle I thought you accepted and then not accepted my answer. Maybe I'm wrong :P

Comment: alex: You're right! First I thought "Oh of course, I'm stupid." Then I thought "Hey, wait a minute ..."

Answer (score 3):

Actually JSOP is a clever workaround for the limitations of the same origin policy but what it is is basically a self-inflicted cross-side scripting attack (remember that JSONP warks by using script tags instead of XHR so you give total control over your entire page to your JSONP data provider - usually they're not evil but sometimes they're incompetent so keep that in mind).

There is a lot of discussions on how to fix the same origin policy in new versions of ECMAScript because clearly it doesn't work if it has to be circumvented to make any kind of mashups. An interesting idea in my opinion is having a cheaper version of XHR that would send no cookies or useless headers and so would be able to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks but still allowing safe mashups without giving the data provider total access to your page. But we still have to wait for it.

Comment: Right, disallow (or sandbox) cookies and whatever headers can be abused on requests to foreign domains. It doesn't really sound so difficult to fix. XHR isn't defined by ECMAScript though, it's defined by W3C.